R MariaDB connection failure: Can't create more than max_prepared_stmt_count statements (current value: 16382) [1461]
I have been using R for several months to read and analyze the system parameters from the Maria DB. Since yesterday it is no longer possible to establish a connection to the database. I always get the error:
Fehler: Can't create more than max_prepared_stmt_count statements (current value: 16382) [1461]
Neither the database nor the R script has been changed.
Below the R script used:
library(RMariaDB)
con <- dbConnect(RMariaDB::MariaDB(), 
                 host = "10.10.20.95",
                 username = "admin",
                 password = "1234",
                 group = "maschine1",
                 port = 3306)

After a few trials I realized that the error is only displayed if a password is set in the script.
I checked the connection to mariaDB with heidiSQL and the same connection parameters and this works fine.
